# need to enable space button of keyboard

Tags: javascript, jquery

i am using this code to disable special characters, and it is working correctly but it is is not allowing to add space in it

Thanks in advance

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
    Alphanumeric value:
    <input type="text" id="text1" onkeypress="return IsAlphaNumeric(event);" ondrop="return false;"
        onpaste="return false;" />
    <span id="error" style="color: Red; display: none">* Special Characters not allowed</span>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var specialKeys = new Array();
        specialKeys.push(8); //Backspace
        specialKeys.push(9); //Tab
        specialKeys.push(46); //Delete
        specialKeys.push(36); //Home
        specialKeys.push(35); //End
        specialKeys.push(37); //Left
        specialKeys.push(39); //Right
        function IsAlphaNumeric(e) {
            var keyCode = e.keyCode == 0 ? e.charCode : e.keyCode;
            var ret = ((keyCode >= 48 && keyCode <= 57) || (keyCode >= 65 && keyCode <= 90) || (keyCode >= 97 && keyCode <= 122) || (specialKeys.indexOf(e.keyCode) != -1 && e.charCode != e.keyCode));
            document.getElementById("error").style.display = ret ? "none" : "inline";
            return ret;
        }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Add a `specialKey` value for space? (it's 32)

Comment: No sense in defining your array like that. `var specialKeys = [8, 9, 46, ..., 39];` should be fine.

Comment: @jasonscript i have added but it is not working

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a jsFiddle illustrating a solution.

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kolban/na82tr0k/)

The JavaScript code becomes:

```
var specialKeys = new Array();
specialKeys.push(8); //Backspace
specialKeys.push(9); //Tab
specialKeys.push(46); //Delete
specialKeys.push(36); //Home
specialKeys.push(35); //End
specialKeys.push(37); //Left
specialKeys.push(39); //Right
function IsAlphaNumeric(e) {
    var keyCode = e.keyCode == 0 ? e.charCode : e.keyCode;
    var ret = ((keyCode == 32) || (keyCode >= 48 && keyCode <= 57) || (keyCode >= 65 && keyCode <= 90) || (keyCode >= 97 && keyCode <= 122) || (specialKeys.indexOf(e.keyCode) != -1 && e.charCode != e.keyCode));
    document.getElementById("error").style.display = ret ? "none" : "inline";
    return ret;
}
```

The trick was to allow a keyCode equal to 32.

Comment: Thank you so much @Kolban i have one more problem i wanna enable CTLR button in it

Comment: Howdy ... what is "CTLR" button?

Comment: in this textbox i could not paste anything i just want to enable it kindly help

Comment: @Chakri - Wouldn't the Control key be considered a "modifier" of existing keys?  I can see it being used as an "action" key on a game but for a text input string, I don't think it introduces any new data into the field.

Comment: @Subhan ... if you want to be able to paste, remove the "onpaste" section of your HTML.

Comment: @Kolban If remove onpaste from html it will allow special characters while pasting.

Comment: @Gowri - Yes ... I think it would.  What one would have to do is provide a function to be called by the onpaste event and then get the clipboard data that is being pasted and then for each character in the pasted text ask if it were allowable and only if ALL were allowable, return true otherwise return false.  This would (opinion) mean refactoring the code to write a "CheckValid(char)" function and call that from both "IsAlphaNumeric" and from the onpaste function.

Answer (score 0):

Add Special key value for space.

It is 32.

Refer for others too :-

http://css-tricks.com/snippets/javascript/javascript-keycodes/